# How to scroll a LinearLayout horizontally?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a LinearLayout that I do larger than the screen. I want to scroll that in horizontal. I have the next code but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gm_movimientos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: When the linearlayout is larger than the screen, I try to scroll horizontal but nothing happen.

Comment: Make sure you check the wraps on your layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HorizontalScrollView width needs to be set to either match_parent or a fixed size.  Right now the ScrollView is expanding to the same dimensions of the LinearLayout (i.e. its bounds are also going off of the screen).

Comment: I have set the HorizontalScrollView first to match_parent and next to 2000dp (to be sure that is larger than the LinearLayout) but is still not working :(

Comment: The HorizontalScrollView actually needs to be smaller than the LinearLayout.  You scroll within the visible size boundaries of the ScrollView.

Comment: no it won't work. You can define the width or height greater than the device width or height but it will only occupy the device width or height and not a single dpi greater than that.

Comment: Now works, appears the HorizontalScrollView! Thank you very much!

Comment: but if your view has content(other views or bitmap) greater than the device width then horizontal scroll view will work...

Comment: it's good to hear that your code works now. But one thing you should always use with scroll view like horizontal scroll view or a scroll view is android:fillViewport="true". It enables the child of the scroll view to occupy the scroll view's full size when the child size is less than that of the scroll view.

Comment: You're right karn, the layout is not larger than the screen, I need to be sure that the canvas inside is larger to do the scroll works.